# Value lookup using key or vice versa

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

First of all, apologies for the nasty title. I will correct it later.

I have some data like below,

`"BOULEVARD","BOUL","BOULV", "BLVD"`

I need a data structure that is O(1) for looking up any of this words by other. For example, if I use a dictionary I would need to store this keys/values like this, which looks odd to me,

```
abbr.Add("BLVD", new List<string> { "BOULEVARD","BOUL","BOULV", "BLVD" });
abbr.Add("BOUL", new List<string> { "BOULEVARD", "BOUL", "BOULV", "BLVD" });
abbr.Add("BOULV", new List<string> { "BOULEVARD", "BOUL", "BOULV", "BLVD" });
abbr.Add("BOULEVARD", new List<string> { "BOULEVARD", "BOUL", "BOULV", "BLVD" });
```

Which data structure to use to keep this data appropriate to my querying terms?

Thanks in advance

Comment: instead of making a new list for each .Add, you could use the same list.  or better yet, as HashSet<string> instead of a list.  I don't know that you can get to O(1) though.....

Comment: How do want to use your structure? Something like "give me all words that belong to BLVD" or "do BLVD and BOUL are the same"?

Comment: @MatthiasG - Correct. "give me all words that belong to BLVD" or "give me all words that belong to BOUL" or  "give me all words that belong to BOULV" should gives me same set of values

Comment: @JohnGardner - I believe hashmaps are O(1) because you calculate the hash, then calculate which bucket to look in, and you're there.  That does not vary depending on collection size.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong [that's not to say that O(1) time is fast, just that it's fairly unvarying]

Comment: I am still confused to give a right title for this question so that any one can find it while searching for it. Is this title is appropriate. Volunteers are welcome to edit the title that is more appropriate to the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Petar Minchev already said, you can split your list into an list of groups and a list of keys that points to this group. To simplify this (in usage) you can write an own implementation of `IDictionary` and use the `Add` method to build those groups. I gave it a try and it seems to work. Here are the important parts of the implementation:

```
public class GroupedDictionary<T> : IDictionary<T,IList<T>>
{
    private Dictionary<T, int> _keys;
    private Dictionary<int, IList<T>> _valueGroups;

    public GroupedDictionary()
    {
        _keys = new Dictionary<T, int>();
        _valueGroups = new Dictionary<int, IList<T>>();
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<T, IList<T>> item)
    {
        Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public void Add(T key, IList<T> value)
    {
        // look if some of the values already exist
        int existingGroupKey = -1;
        foreach (T v in value)
        {
            if (_keys.Keys.Contains(v))
            {
                existingGroupKey = _keys[v];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (existingGroupKey == -1)
        {
            // new group
            int newGroupKey = _valueGroups.Count;
            _valueGroups.Add(newGroupKey, new List<T>(value));
            _valueGroups[newGroupKey].Add(key);
            foreach (T v in value)
            {
                _keys.Add(v, newGroupKey);
            }
            _keys.Add(key, newGroupKey);
        }
        else
        {
            // existing group
            _valueGroups[existingGroupKey].Add(key);
            // add items that are new
            foreach (T v in value)
            {
                if(!_valueGroups[existingGroupKey].Contains(v))
                {
                    _valueGroups[existingGroupKey].Add(v);
                }
            }
            // add new keys
            _keys.Add(key, existingGroupKey);
            foreach (T v in value)
            {
                if (!_keys.Keys.Contains(v))
                {
                    _keys.Add(v, existingGroupKey);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public IList<T> this[T key]
    {
        get { return _valueGroups[_keys[key]]; }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

The usage could look like this:

```
var groupedDictionary = new GroupedDictionary<string>();
groupedDictionary.Add("BLVD", new List<string> {"BOUL", "BOULV"}); // after that three keys exist and one list of three items
groupedDictionary.Add("BOULEVARD", new List<string> {"BLVD"}); // now there is a fourth key and the key is added to the existing list instance
var items = groupedDictionary["BOULV"]; // will give you the list with four items
```

Sure it is a lot of work to implement the whole interface but it will give to an encapsulated class that you don't have to worry about, after it is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Create two `HashMap` - one maps word to a group number. And the other one maps group number to a list of words. This way you save some memory.

```
Map<String, Integer> - Word to Group Number
Map<Integer, List<String>> - Group Number to a list of words
```

You need two `O(1)` lookups - first to get the group number and then by it - get the list of words.

Comment: @L.B - Ah it is C# - so it is Dictionary there. It is the same like HashMap in Java.

Comment: @Chris Shain - To a group you map only one list of words. Look at the code of the OP - he uses the same list four times. I use it one time for the group.

Comment: Ah, but then why not just map to a single instance of the list directly as per my answer?

Comment: @Chris Shain - You may want to iterate over all groups. Otherwise if you don't want that, you are right:)

Comment: if you're just going to have a group number, why even have a secondary mapping?  why not have it be an index into an array of lists of words?

Comment: @John Gardner - That is also an option, if the group numbers will be consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming abbr is a `Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<String>>`, you could use the following function:

```
public static void IndexAbbreviations(IEnumerable<String> abbreviations) {
    for (var a in abbreviations)
        abbr.Add(a, abbreviations);
}
```

This will populate the dictionary with the provided list of abbreviations such that when any of them is looked up in the dictionary. It is slightly better than the example code you provided, because I am not creating a new object for each value.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), "Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) class is implemented as a hash table."

Comment: this might be my favorite implementation so far.  simple but effective.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of dictionary looks fine to me. As mentioned above, you should use the same list to be referenced in the dictionary. The code could go something like this:

```
var allAbrList = new List<List<string>>
                 {
                    new List<string> {"BOULEVARD", "BOUL", "BOULV", "BLVD"},
                    new List<string> {"STREET", "ST", "STR"},
                    // ...
                 };

var allAbrLookup = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (List<string> list in allAbrList)
{
    foreach (string abbr in list)
    {
        allAbrLookup.Add(abbr, list);
    }
}
```

The last part could be converted into LINQ to have less code, but this way it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't create a new list for each key, then a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` will be fast and reasonably memory-efficient as long as the amount of data isn't enormous.  You might also be able to get a little extra benefit from reusing the strings themselves, though the optimizer might take care of that for you anyway.

```
var abbr = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>;

var values = new List<string> { "BOULEVARD","BOUL","BOULV", "BLVD" };

foreach(var aValue in values) abbr.add(value, values);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to define the value part of your dictionary as a `List<string>` object, but perhaps that is your requirement.  This answer assumes that you just want to know whether the word essentially means "Boulevard".

I would pick one value as the "official" value and map all of the other values to it, like this:

```
        var abbr = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

        abbr.Add("BLVD", "BLVD"); // this line may be optional
        abbr.Add("BOUL", "BLVD");
        abbr.Add("BOULV", "BLVD");
        abbr.Add("BOULEVARD", "BLVD");
```

Alternatively, you could define an enum for the value part of the dictionary, as shown below:

```
    enum AddressLine1Suffix
    {
        Road,
        Street,
        Avenue,
        Boulevard,
    }


        var abbr = new Dictionary<string, AddressLine1Suffix>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

        abbr.Add("BLVD", AddressLine1Suffix.Boulevard);
        abbr.Add("BOUL", AddressLine1Suffix.Boulevard);
        abbr.Add("BOULV", AddressLine1Suffix.Boulevard);
        abbr.Add("BOULEVARD", AddressLine1Suffix.Boulevard);
```